# How to enforce running a playbook on a Vagrant machine?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I wrote a playbook which installs Docker.

```
---

- name: Install dependencies
  apt: name={{ item }} state=present update_cache=yes
  with_items:
    - linux-image-generic-lts-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}
    - linux-headers-generic-lts-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}
  become: true

- name: Add Docker repository key
  apt_key:
    id: 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
    keyserver: hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
    state: present
  register: add_repository_key
  become: true

- name: Add Docker repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main'
    state: present
  become: true

- name: Install Docker
  apt:
    name: docker
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  become: true

- name: Verify the service is running
  service:
    name: docker
    enabled: yes
    state: started
  become: true
```

I'm up'ing a vagrant machine which is configured to use that playbook.

**Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/tmp/project",create: true
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80 , auto_correct: true

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    # Name of machine
    v.name = "default"
    # Machine memory
    v.memory = 1024
    # Number of cpu's
    v.cpus = 2
    # This option makes the NAT engine use the host's resolver mechanisms to handle DNS requests
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    # Enabling the I/O APIC is required for 64-bit guest operating systems; it is also required if you want to use more than one virtual CPU in a virtual machine.
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ioapic", "on"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    # Sets the playbook to use when machine is up'ed
    ansible.playbook = "deploy/main.yml"
  end

end
```

But for some reason, that's the output I get and docker is not installed on the vagrant machine:

```
$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

Is this the right way to do that?

Is there a command which lets me play a playbook on a running Vagrant machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wrote a playbook which installs docker.
>
> ```
> ---
> - name: Install dependencies
>   apt: name={{ item }} state=present update_cache=yes
>   with_items:
>     - linux-image-generic-lts-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}
>     - linux-headers-generic-lts-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}
>   become: true
> ```

No, you have not written a playbook. You have written a YAML file containing a list of Ansible tasks.

[Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html) contain a list of plays, and plays are YAML dictionaries which, for Ansible to work, at minimum must contain `hosts` key. In a typical play, the list of tasks is defined in `tasks` key.

So for your file to be a playbook you'd at least need:

```
- hosts: default

  tasks:
    - name: Install dependencies
      apt: name={{ item }} state=present update_cache=yes
      with_items:
        - linux-image-generic-lts-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}
        - linux-headers-generic-lts-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}
      become: true
```

<sup>**Note**: `default` here refers to the name of the machine defined in your Vagrantfile (`v.name = "default"`) not anything Ansible-default.</sup>

---

> Is there a command which lets me play a playbook on a running Vagrant machine?

You can run the playbook defined in the Vagrant file with:

```
vagrant provision
```

To run another one, you'd just use `ansible-playbook`, but you must point to the Vagrant's inventory file, you must also use `vagrant` as the `remote_user`:

```
ansible-playbook -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory playbook.yml
```